# Github WebHooks get branch details

Tags: php, git, github, webhooks

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Create a Github webhook (done)
2. Create a PHP/Node application GIHook points to (done)
3. Process response (here is where problem lies)
4. Depending on branch commited to, make a request to dev or live server to execute update.sh (done)

Issue is the GIHook sends me this:

```
{
"REQUEST_METHOD":"GET",
"CONTENT_TYPE":"application\/json",
"headers":{
"Content-Type":"application\/json",
"X-Hub-Signature-256":"sha256=xxxx",
"X-Hub-Signature":"sha1=xxx",
"X-Github-Hook-Installation-Target-Type":"repository",
"X-Github-Hook-Installation-Target-Id":"xxx",
"X-Github-Hook-Id":"xxx",
"X-Github-Event":"push",
"X-Github-Delivery":"xxx",
"Referer":"webhook url called",
"Accept":"*\/*",
"User-Agent":"GitHub-Hookshot\/8338482",
"Connection":"close",
"X-Accel-Internal":"\/internal-nginx-static-location",
"X-Real-Ip":"xxx",
"Host":"xxxx"
},
"JSON":"",
"POST":[],
"GET":[],
"payload":null
},
```

Which doesn't tell me which branch was commited to.

So then I read a few more bits and pieces and found there is more information to be obtained but the question is how. So I would assumeed I would call an api and passback an id or something and after some googling it looked like this was the way. So I tested:

```
# :HOOK_ID = X-Github-Hook-Id
curl -o -v - https://api.github.com/repos/:GitHubUserNameInUrl/:PrivateRepo/hooks/:HOOK_ID
```

and done the same with php via curl and file get contents only to all return the same result:

```
{
"message": "Not Found",
"documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository-webhook"
}
```

Anyone have an idea how to get the payload from the response the webhook gives me (PHP or Node)?

Thanks

D

RESPONSE 1
Thanks for that reply, but I don't get any information such as you get from your webhook. Here is the code I use to test my response data when the webhook calls my url. JSON is always "" and POST,GET are always empty arrays [].

```
$file = 'log.json';

$dte = date("d-m-y H:i:s");
$headers = getallheaders();
$data = [];
$data["date"] = $dte;
$data["REQUEST_METHOD"] = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
$data["CONTENT_TYPE"] = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];
$data["headers"] = $headers;
$data["JSON"] = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); // Always null || ""
$data["POST"] = $_POST; // Always []
$data["GET"] = $_GET; // Always []


$hookid = $headers["X-Github-Hook-Id"];
$data["hook_id"] = $hookid;

$APIUrl = "https://api.github.com/repos";
$url = $APIUrl . "/GITHUB_USER/REPO/hooks/".$hookid;
$data["callback"] = $url;

// Using file_get_contents
// $result = file_get_contents($url);
// $payload = json_decode($result, true);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$payload = json_decode($result, true);
$data["payload"] = $payload;

$out = json_encode($data) . ",\n";
file_put_contents($file, $out, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 1):

NGINX Redirect from / to /index.php was the issue, seems all data is not being fully passed via the redirect from / to index.php.

SOLUTION
Set webhook to point to the file directly, in this case index.php

Answer (score 0):

### Check your code which is decoding the payload.

For `"X-Github-Event":"push",` and `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the payload is percent encoded JSON not `null`

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Host: lcherone.requestcatcher.com
Connection: close
Accept: */*
Connection: close
Content-Length: 11363
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: GitHub-Hookshot/8338482
X-Github-Delivery: e39cc102-318e-11eb-8301-d4f46caa1c8a
X-Github-Event: push
X-Github-Hook-Id: 265270862
X-Github-Hook-Installation-Target-Id: 316492816
X-Github-Hook-Installation-Target-Type: repository
X-Hub-Signature: sha1=0baa6d15c266c08111508642607acc86b15f1f43
X-Hub-Signature-256: sha256=6c58a95d4a5a3cde91bcc2621d6608a5190b1178be197db00ed6dd4364137898

payload=%7B%22ref%22%3A%22refs%2Fheads%2Fmain%22%2C%22before%22%3A%220000000000000000000000000000000000000000%22%2C%22after%22%3A%224872b45f3df6d2b0485a69adb8c7476934be7629%22%2C%22repository%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A316492816%2C%22node_id%22%3A%22MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkzMTY0OTI4MTY%3D%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22wightsystems%22%2C%22full_name%22%3A%22wightsystems%2Fwightsystems%22%2C%22private%22%3Afalse%2C%22owner%22%3A%7...snip
```

Which to decode you would do:

`$payload = json_decode(urldecode($_POST['payload']));` (might not need urldecode, I didnt check)

Whilst if you choose `Content-Type: application/json` the payload is raw json:

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Host: lcherone.requestcatcher.com
Connection: close
Accept: */*
Connection: close
Content-Length: 8176
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: GitHub-Hookshot/8338482
X-Github-Delivery: 2c350428-3190-11eb-90a9-13e895014cf2
X-Github-Event: push
X-Github-Hook-Id: 265270862
X-Github-Hook-Installation-Target-Id: 316492816
X-Github-Hook-Installation-Target-Type: repository
X-Hub-Signature: sha1=20ea83c65ee1771913829db5553a13c09d5d44c0
X-Hub-Signature-256: sha256=eb89d594cfa830be18d11f00d502bd0fdb118fa9017496a8bf52c6a286b1ced6

{"ref":"refs/heads/main","before":"4872b45f3df6d2b0485a69adb8c7476934be7629","after":"ab03e7b705440088a6e22f06d31a660c8185bcb6","repository":{"id":316492816,"node_id":"MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkzMTY0OTI4MTY=","name":"wightsystems","full_name":"wightsystems/wightsystems","private":false,"owner":...snip}
```

Which would be:

`$payload = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Once decode it has a bunch of data, including the branch which is `ref` and to access it would be:

`echo str_replace('refs/heads/', '', $payload->ref);`

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ref] => refs/heads/main
    [before] => 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    [after] => 4872b45f3df6d2b0485a69adb8c7476934be7629
    ...snip
```

Comment: I don't get those details, added code under RESPONSE 1 in main question to reply to you. My JSON php://input is always null, the webhook is set to json mode.

Comment: check whats sent in the edit webhook page at the bottom (Recent Deliveries). I highly doubt they would have sent null if so then you should report it, which is why I said *Check your code which is decoding the payload.* as the payload does not contain `},
"JSON":"",
"POST":[],
"GET":[],` so it must be your code. Its would help if you added your webhook receiver code.

Comment: In Github webhooks the log shows it sent a payload and with the information I need but what my script receives is null when i use file_get_contents("php://input"). The "JSON":"", "POST":[], "GET":[] is just my php test code dumping stuff out to a text file so I can see what is going on.

Comment: I've also got the github webhook set to send everything.

Comment: did you set it to send application/json? if so can you add your code.. basically, the webhook doesn't send `null`

Comment: ok, so add `$data["JSON"] = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));` and check its sent as json.. http://imgur.com/fx39qr4l.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225258/discussion-between-darcey-and-lawrence-cherone).